# Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address[3] memory

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm getting error

```
Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address[3] memory.
```

function in which I'm getting this error is

```
function initiateTransaction( address payable _to, uint _amount ) public onlyUser returns(uint txnId) {
        transaction memory newTxn;
        newTxn.id = ++txnCount;
        newTxn.amount = _amount;
        newTxn.to = _to;
        newTxn.initiatedBy = msg.sender;
        newTxn.signedBy.push(msg.sender); // I'm getting error here.
        
    }
```

I've defined the struct as follows

```
    struct transaction {
        uint id;
        uint amount;
        address payable to;
        address initiatedBy;
        address[3] signedBy;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`signedBy` is a fixed-size array, so you cannot resize it by using `push()`.

You need to keep track of how many non-zero values are in the array and rewrite the correct item. (Or calculate the index dynamically, but that would be less optimized in terms of gas costs.)

```
struct transaction {
    uint id;
    uint amount;
    address payable to;
    address initiatedBy;
    uint signersCount; // default value 0
    address[3] signedBy;
}

function initiateTransaction( address payable _to, uint _amount ) public onlyUser returns(uint txnId) {
    transaction memory newTxn;
    newTxn.id = ++txnCount;
    newTxn.amount = _amount;
    newTxn.to = _to;
    newTxn.initiatedBy = msg.sender;
    // retrieve `signersCount`, use it as the `signedBy` index, and then increment it
    newTxn.signedBy[newTxn.signersCount++] = msg.sender;
}
```